# C code from Fortran: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, fortran

I'm trying to compile a Fortran source code (which I didn't write) using `gfortran`. The code calls a C function, `drand48.c`, whose source is in the same folder.

Problem is, when I do:

```
gfortran -o filename.exe filename.f drand48.c
```

I get the following error message:

```
drand48.c:1:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

#include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Now, I am sure that I HAVE the standard library, because I use it all the time in C (I just compiled another C code with `#include <´ and it goes).

What can I do? Thanks!

PS My OS is OSX

Comment: You cannot compile C code with the Fortran compiler. You must compile the Fortran and C code into separate objects with the respective compilers which you can then link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the same compiler to compile C and Fortran. Instead, you should first compile objects from each of the source files with the appropriate compiler:

```
gcc -c -o ccode.o ccode.c
gfortran -c -o fcode fcode.f
```

The `-c` option tells the compiler in this case to create objects, not an executable.

Then link these objects. Because Fortran needs to link to its runtime library, use the Fortran compiler which you used to create the Fortran objects to link all objects and create an executable:

```
gfortran ccode.o fcode.o -o myprogram
```

If you have to do this frequently, you should set up a Makefile.

Comment: -1 This is simply not true or way too simplified. On my system call to gfortran can compile a C code just fine. C and Fortran sources can be combined in a single call and will be compiled by the right frontend. I challange you to find an example when a call of gfortran to a C code will fail in Linux or to state on which systems it fails to compile them.

Comment: More specifically, the GCC commands have `-x` option to specify  the language they should compile. They are capable to compile multiple languages. If this option is not used, the language is determined from file suffixes. If you cannot compile C source files using gfortran, something is wrong with your GCC. Compiling Fortran files with `gcc` should result in missing `libgfortran` when linking, but not by a compile error.

Comment: Okay, turns out that you can actually mix languages with `gcc` and `gfortran` if you use the compiler that is used for the unit that compiles tha main program. I didn't know that. I also find it quite messy, because you probably want different sets of flags for each language. The two-step approach of separate compilation and linking seems to have resolved the OP's problem, too.